# Since FirebaseSimpleLogin became deprecated , myRef authUser returns "simplelogin:userid"

Tags: ios, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

Since https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-10-03-major-updates-to-firebase-user-auth.html, after authenticating a user with `myRef authUser` I get `"simplelogin:userid"`

I haven't found this documented, is it normal? Should I just go on and strip the "simplelogin:" part to get the user id?

Comment: There's not enough info here to understand how you've arrived at this. Please [provide an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when stating that something has stopped working so we can verify and troubleshoot with you. Otherwise, we're just taking stabs in the dark.

Comment: here you are http://pastebin.com/2wXr5RRN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry, you're doing it right. We still have this structure so we don't break anyone who has upgraded.

It's correct behavior to see a uid with the `simplelogin:userid` format.

Answer (score 0):

It's not broken for me. According to the docs just get the uid property from the user object returned upon successful authentication. Can you post a jsfiddle if you still have problems?

```
var myRef = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com");
var authClient = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(myRef, function(error, user) {
  if (error) {
    // an error occurred while attempting login
    console.log(error);
  } else if (user) {
    // user authenticated with Firebase

    console.log("User ID: " + user.uid + ", Provider: " + user.provider);
  } else {
    // user is logged out
  }
});
```

Comment: If you see my post and check here https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html you will see that Simple Login is deprecated now.Plus I am talking about iOS, not web